# Is it possible to get inheritance from whenever I want, from whomever I want?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is it possible to get [inheritance](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Inheritance) (someone dies and a courier gives me money) whenever I want, from whomever I want, in the base game?

I've heard that you can get Inheritance when you kill something enthralled by the Bend Will Shout from Dragonborn.

But is it possible to trigger inheritance for anyone I want, from Bandits to Dragons, in the base game.

Comment: Is the "inheritance" that you're talking about also the same as when somebody that favours you dies, you get a sum of money?

Comment: @PlanetAlexander - Yes.

Comment: It is not like you get the loot from said person/dragon. You just get a small amount of septims, don't know why you would even bother with 100 septims of inheritance.

Comment: @Mixxiphold - Yeah, I know, but is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Yes, but."

You can earn an inheritance from anyone, it seems: the `WIKill03` script that drives the inheritance quest doesn't seem to have any conditions on it that restrict potential bequeathals to actors of specific factions, based on poking around in the scripts (`WIKill03Script` and `QF_WIKill03_001BFF2` as well as the base world interaction, quest and courier scripts). Your disposition with the deceased has to be high enough, otherwise the reward scales to zero and nothing will happen, but otherwise you can get inheritance letters delivered from random bandits, et cetera.

However, whether or not you actually ever *get* the award is gated by a bunch of complex factors relating to how often the quest can re-occur (the inheritance quest is on a ~40 day timer, if I recall correctly), what other potentially higher-priority quests were running, and so on. Most of those factors are rather difficult for you to control in any meaningful way, so you can't easily set up an on-demand payout from this question by killing somebody at any time you want.